# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined but i'm using arrow functions and i tried using bind(this) but it doesn't go away

Tags: reactjs

```
//buttons component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Screen from "./Screen";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";
import Toggle from "./Toggle";
import "../scss/app.scss";

class App extends Component{
    state = {theme:false, screenOutput:""};

    toggleTheme = () => {
        if(this.state.theme === false){
            this.setState({theme: true});
        }
        else{
            this.setState({theme:false});
        }
        console.log(this.state.theme);
    }

    getInputForScreen = (data) => {
        this.setState({screenOutput:data});
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div className={this.state.theme ? "background light" : "background dark"}>
                <div className="calculator" >
                    <Screen output={this.state.screenOutput}/>
                    <Buttons getScreenData={this.getInputForScreen.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                <Toggle toggleTheme={this.toggleTheme.bind(this)} theme={this.state.theme}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

//buttons component

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Buttons extends Component{
    state = {output:""};
    
    getInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({output:e.currentTarget.innerHTML});
        this.props.getInputForScreen(this.state.output);
        console.log(this.state.output);
    }

    

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="buttons">
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button red">C</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">(</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">)</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button orange">/</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">7</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">8</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">9</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button orange">X</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">4</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">5</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">6</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button orange">-</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">1</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">2</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">3</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button orange">+</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button zero">0</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button">.</div>
                <div onClick={this.getInput} className="individual-button green">=</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }

export default Buttons;


//screen component
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Screen = (props) => {
    //
    return(
        <div className="screen">
            <div className="total">{this.props.output}</div> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default Screen;
```

So I'm trying to create the function on a calculator that displays the value on the screen when each button is pressed but I'm getting an error ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
but all my functions are arrow functions so I'm really confused. I even tried using the bind(this) method but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's an arrow function that get `props` as an argument, so you should access that argument as is. without `this`:

```
const Screen = (props) => {
    //
    return(
        <div className="screen">
            <div className="total">{props.output}</div> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Edit:**

As for your following question in the comments section:
propname `getInputForScreen` does not exists, the right propname you pass to the children is `getScreenData`. So you should change it to `this.props.getScreenData(this.state.output);`

Comment: thank you for that, it removed that error but it came up with this error "TypeError: this.props.getInputForScreen is not a function"

Comment: @EvanKalvis there is no such prop as `getInputForScreen`. You pass that function to `Button` as a prop named `getScreenData`. So you should access `this.props.getScreenData(this.state.output);`

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your functions with your class by constructor. for example:

```
class App extends Component{
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
   theme:false, 
   screenOutput:""
 }

 this.toggleTheme = this.toggleTheme.bind(this);
 this.getInputForScreen = this.getInputForScreen.bind(this);
 }

toggleTheme = () => {
    if(this.state.theme === false){
        this.setState({theme: true});
    }
    else{
        this.setState({theme:false});
    }
    console.log(this.state.theme);
}

getInputForScreen = (data) => {
    this.setState({screenOutput:data});
}

render(){

    return(
        <div className={this.state.theme ? "background light" : "background dark"}>
            <div className="calculator" >
                <Screen output={this.state.screenOutput}/>
                <Buttons getScreenData={this.getInputForScreen}/>
            </div>
            <Toggle toggleTheme={this.toggleTheme} theme={this.state.theme}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default App;

Comment: i tried it but it still comes up with the same error